# Regex diacritics problem

Tags: php, regex, cakephp, diacritics

I am trying to validate some user inputs, but my regex fails when it encounters diacritics. I am talking about characters like `ăĂ` and so on.

What should I add to the regex code so it should also validate diacritics from within inputs?

Thank you!

P.S.: If it matters, I am using PHP with CakePHP framework.

This is the piece of code I am currently using for validating user input: `return preg_match('|^[0-9a-zA-Z_-\s]*$|', $value);`

Comment: How can we help you if you don't tell us what your regex is?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add it!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you want to match letters, then allowing Unicode letters should help:

Use `/\p{L}+/u` for example if you want to match a sequence of letters. Don't forget the `/u` (Unicode) modifier.

In your case:

```
return preg_match('|^[0-9\p{L}_\s-]*$|u', $value);
```

should work.

As an aside, it's probably not a good idea to use `|` as a regex delimiter. For the current regex `/` would do just fine; other alternatives are `~` or `#` because they seldom occur in text and don't have any special meaning in regexes.